# Inertiajs php artisan start-ssr not running for two app on same server

Tags: digital-ocean, laravel

I have two applications that I have deployed to Digital Ocean using Laravel Forge. Both is building using Laravel, Vue, Inertia, Tailwindcss Stack. (inertia 1.0) When I try to start daemon for starting SSR for both server... the port seems to conflict and does not run the daemon as expected. If there is only one site.. everything works perfectly.

What is the issues.. and what is the right way of doing it.

Also another issue is the when I enter website2.com on browers it automatically redirects to website1.com. Both are on the same digital ocean droplet. But works good when I type the full url https://website2.com